# How does one guarantee $ f(h) = max(0 , W^T h + b ) $ to be piece wise linear in a bounded positive hypercube?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, measure-theory, optimization, constraints

Consider:

$$ f(h) = max(0, W^T h + b ) = max( 0, g(h,W,b) )$$

the goal is to choose $W$ and $b$ such that given a bounded (positive) domain the function $f(h)$ is piece wise linear **in the given domain** (note the region is fixed a priori and cannot be changed). I thought about this a little and it seems that it equivalently means that $f(h) = 0$ for some region or even better $g(h,W,b) < 0$. Ideally $h \in \mathbb{R}^D$ and $h$ is bounded, for example each coordinate $h_i \in [0, K]$ for some constant $K \in \mathbb{R}$.

To start this off I consider a case that I could visualize: $h \in \mathbb{R}^2$. I considered the bounded region $h \in \mathbb{R}^2$ Thus we have:

$$ f_2(h) = max(0, W_1 h_1 + W_2 h_2 + b ) = max( 0, g_2(h,W,b) ) $$

In this case its quite easy to do the task because one can even just go to mathematica a visualize the problem and choose the numbers so that there is a region that its linear and another that is not. I quickly noticed that given only a positive hypercube one could set $b = 0$ (or really small) and then just have $W_1, W_2$ opposite signs and not differ in magnitude to much (if they differ by a lot then $-W_2$ would eat up the values and drive them to be negative which would be driven to zero by the max, similarly if $W_1$ is to large then because the max never sees a negative value it ends up just being a linear function). Given a fixed bound its not to hard to play around with this simple case.

However, when it comes up to a more interesting case like $\mathbb{R}^4$ (the one I am mostly interested) I found it harder to reason how to choose $W^T$ and $b$. Is there a systematic to tackle this problem given a fixed positive hypercube to choose $W$ and $b$ such that there is always a region that is piece wise linear? If its not possible is it **at least** possible to guarantee that **some** region is piece wise linear or **maximize** the area/volume where the function is piece wise linear?

Obviously my worry is that if the region is enclosed in such a way that $f(h)$ is always positive so it doesn’t have a region where its zero (or similarly its always zero and never linear). Given a positive hypercube, is it possible to guarantee that $f(h)$ has some region that is zero? I'm mostly interested right now at 4D but anything that generalizes would be fantastic/excellent!

Essentially as the comments have pointed out, a different way to express the question is to require the **kink** of $f(x)$ to lie inside the prescribed hypercube.

Comment: $f$ is piecewise linear for any $W$ and $b$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @LinAlg short answer: The key is that it has to be piece wise linear in the restricted hypercube/space, otherwise its trivial as you noticed. Long answer: consider the super simple example, consider 1D $f(x) = max(0,Wx+b)$ and $W =1, b=0$. If we impose that the domain is only hypercube (interval in this case) $x \in [1,2]$, then $f(x)$ is just a linear function. However, if the the hypercube is still like that then we could potentially use the bias $b$ to move $Wx + b$ such that there is at least some region that  where $Wx+b < 0$. If we do that then it is piece wise linear.

Comment: You mean affine, not linear. So you want conditions for the kink (break-point) of the piecewise affine function to be inside a prescribed polytope

Comment: The difference between linear and affine is very thin (consider linear regression). One solution approach is to take any $x$ from your hypercube and to find any nontrivial $W$ and $b$ such that $Wx+b=0$.

Comment: @LinAlg hmmm, that sounds promising. Also in my solution I implied that Ideally I'd like to maximize the region where $f(x)$ is piece wise linear. Thus, something like the $x \in [0,K]^D$ in the center would be nice since its more likely to cover a lot of space. What do you think?

Comment: @JohanLöfberg yes, I think that is one of the conditions I want; the kink is in the prescribed space. Ideally it would be nice if its not only inside but also sufficiently inside for the function to be clearly piece wise linear (I don't really know why affine...so I'll stick with the vocabulary I understand). So having the power to control the kink is important. Also I wrote the hypercube to include the edges, so it would be a unsatisfactory solution to have the kink lie exactly at the edge, since that wouldn't really satisfy the conditions that I want (i.e. being clearly piecewise linear).

Comment: I would look at KKT conditions for the problem of minimizing $(W^Tx + b)^2$ in a polytope $Ax\leq c$ (generalization of your set). You want the minimal value to be $0$, plug into KKT.